# Regex grouping inside of a ignoring repeating group

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the following text:

```
Example 1: 'lun et mer et mar'

Example 2: 'lun. et mer. - mar.'

Example 3: 'lun a ven'

Negative example 4 (must not match): 'sept à juin'

Negative example 5 (must not match): 'foo bar'

Negative example 6 (must not match): '9h30 - 18h'
```

I'm trying to group each word, so the desired result would be:

```
Example 1: ['lun', 'et', 'mer', 'et', 'mar']

Example 2: ['lun', 'et', 'mer', '-', 'mar']

Example 3: ['lun', 'a', 'ven']
```

The regex that I tried is [here](https://regex101.com/r/jPt0On/1):

```
(?:((lun|mar|mer)\.?\s*(\-|au|a|à|et)?\s*)+)
```

But, as a result, I get only the last word 'mar', twice.

I would say that I have [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) problem, but I tried what the article suggested without success.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

**NOTE** I need this to be a regex, because I'm parsing an unknown text, and if there's a full match I know with what kind of data I'm dealing with.
For example, this must not match:

```
Mustn't match: 'sept à juin'
```

Comment: What language do you need this in?

Comment: @chrisz in JavaScript

Comment: @chrisz why'd you delete your answer? Looks fine to me.

Comment: Just felt it was low quality. There is a better way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just split on this regex after removing trailing punctuation:

```
/[ ,.]+/
```

Demo:

```js
var str = "lun. et mer. - mar.";
var words = str.replace(/[ .,]+$/, "").split(/[ ,.]+/);
console.log(words);
```

Output:

```
[
  "lun",
  "et",
  "mer",
  "-",
  "mar"
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for me. Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do the following:

```js
let Example1 = 'lun et mer et mar';
let Example2 = 'lun. et mer. - mar.';
let Example3 = 'lun a ven';
let Example4 = 'sept à juinn';

function format(str){
  str = /(lun|mar|mer)/.test(str) ? str : '';
  return str.split(' ').map(i=>i.replace(/[.]/,'')).filter(j=>j)
}
console.log(format(Example1));
console.log(format(Example2));
console.log(format(Example3));
console.log(format(Example4));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for me. Please see my updated answer

Comment: @pegasus, could you explain `won't work for me`..... as the answer in the snippet shows the expected output  for all set of inputs.....

Comment: As an input, I have a raw text, which I must parse to look for a specific data. I updated my question with an example that mustn't be matched - 'sept à juin'

Comment: @pegasus, what should be the condition behind not matching `sept à juin`?

Comment: Business requirements. I should only match `lun|mar|mer` with a couple of special separator characters

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without capturing groups by using the `g` flag to match multiple times:

```js
function words(s) {
  let a = s.match(/[a-z-]+/g);
  console.log(a);
}

words('lun et mer et mar');
words('lun. et mer. - mar.');
words('lun a ven');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for me. Please see my updated answer

Comment: @pegasus please continue to update your question: You stated that “I have the following text”... but your examples are on their own, not embedded within a larger text. Please correct this error in your question. As your question stands, this answer works perfectly.

Comment: Done, please take a look